# How to shorten the width of input field? Bootstrap v5 or CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I can't find a way to reduce the width of the input window. I don't see or find any code that controls the width of the input window. The code below is taken from the [Bootstrap v5 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/), from the form element.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<form>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of using `form-control`, it is taking the full width allotted. You can use the column property like `col-md-4` or other property to make the size you wanted.

Answer (score 16):

The input element in BootStrap v5 is a flex item. To change it's width, just set the input element's `flex-grow` property to `0` and the `flex-basis` property to the value you want for the width (e.g. **100px**) like this:

```
flex-grow: 0;
flex-basis: 100px;
```

Or you can use the flex shorthand property (the second value is for the `flex-shrink` property) like this:

```
flex: 0 1 100px;
```

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```css
/* CSS */
.input-group>input.someInput {flex: 0 1 100px;}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form>
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control someInput" placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Sign up</button> 
     </div>          
 </form>
```

Answer (score 15):

It's pretty simple. Add `w` class like the following examples:

This is the default width of the Bootstrap input element:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Sign up</button> 
   </div>
</form>
```

You will need to reduce it by adding `w-25` class like below:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
   <div class="input-group mb-3 w-25">
      <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Sign up</button> 
   </div>
</form>
```

If you want to reduce it even more or make it bigger, change the `w` class to `w-50`, `w-75`, `w-100`, or `w-auto`.

This is all called [*Bootstrap Utilities Sizing*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/).

Comment: your answer works to reduce width, but it all moves to left side of the page and I can't "center" it.......    I will resubmit the question, as a new question, so you can see the entire program code.....

Comment: @JoeG Try `<center></center>` tag.

Comment: `<center>` tag is **obsolete** and is not recommended to be used, please **do not** use it. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#center)

Comment: thank you for w class reference.

Comment: @kta You're welcome, happy to help. Honestly, I'm glad that my 2 year's answers are still helping people to the day. Also, if you ever had an unnecessary reputation points that you wanted to award, you could award this answer with a bounty (joking that you're 19k) xD

Comment: The smallest size, w-25, is still way too big. How can you make it smaller? I only need at most 5 numbers.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Then you either need to modify [the SCSS and compile yourself](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/sizing/#sass-utilities-api), or use custom CSS styling, values like `w-25` are the default ones offered by Bootstrap.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `size` attribute of `<input>`.

```html
<form>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" aria-label="Email" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" size="20" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Prometeu, that didn't quite work; is there a way you can view my entire code? I have to wait about 90 minutes to ask another question.

Comment: You can edit your snippet from the post or paste a working part of it on some site like http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS file under `input-group` add the width you prefer in percentage followed by the important reference.

```css
.input-group {
    width: 95% !important;
}
```

You will note that everything works but that the input bar is no longer centered. So add in your HTML div class `mx-auto` as well (which stands for "margin x direction auto").

```html
<div class="input-group mx-auto">
```